# Adding javascript code using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a property in Model

```
public CodeString {get; set;}
```

which contains string value something like this

```
<SCRIPT src="http://demo.com/add/091221"> </script><SCRIPT src="http://demo.com/add"> </script>
```

i want to add CodeString property's value to the body section of the view.I am seeing CodeString Value in assigning it to hidden field and alerting the hidden field. But script is not getting added to the head section. I am trying to using this hidden field as follows:

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('head').append($("#PixelCodeString").val());
});
```

Still not seeing the script tag in the generated html page. Folks what's going wrong in this? any ideas?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/3Ubqv/ - seems to be working fine, do you get any errors in your console?

Answer (score 1):

One question: are you putting the raw value there to avoid escaping the `<`?

Anyway, you should not need to put the code in an hidden field and you don't have to put the scripts in the `<head>` tag: you can simply output the content of the property. For example if you are using Razor:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.CodeString)
```

On a side note, if I were you I would use [`getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) from jQuery. That way I can load all my scripts later. To do that you will need to change your property to a `List<>` of script Urls and use getScript for each one.

Comment: Perfect... Tallmaris... I was digging around all the jquery stuff to do this but it was really so easy to do so.. Thanks a lot... :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just view the source, then you will not see that part since it is added through client code.. (***view source*** will only show what was sent from the server)

You can use firebug to see the live DOM and you will find it..

A simple test with

```
<input id="code" value="<script>alert('test');</script>"/>
```

and

```
$('head').append( $('#code').val() );
```

is working fine at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/57AgH/

Answer (score 0):

on your cs page

```
public CodeString {get; set;}
string script="</script>$(document).ready(function () {
         $('head').append($("#CodeString").val()); </script>"

});
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "Your script", script);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        var myCar='@ViewBag.Car'; // Here i am trying to access the ViewBag here
        $("#myCarDiv").html(myCar);
});
</script>
<div id="myCarDiv"></div>
```